# Run a function every time an angular route is navigated to

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I want to run a function every time an Angular route is navigated to.

One option is I just add `myFunction()` to the top of every controller. Seems really repetitive. Is there a better way to run `myFunction()` every time $location changes?

Comment: if you are using ui-router, you can add the result of your function as a resolve object.  You can also use `$routeChangeStart` or `$routeChangeSuccess`.  see the [angular $route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#!/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ui-router, you can simply bind a function to the $rootscope. 
See the stateChange section: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```